# Can a Dictionary be sorted by a different key?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, data-structures

I have a requirement to retrieve an item from a data structure by key.  But I also have a requirement to traverse that data structure in sorted order, using a field other than the key.

Something like this (pseudocode, for illustrative purposes only):

```
var list = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TSortField, TItem>();
```

How would I do this?  Is there a way to use a single data structure, or do I need to roll my own?

**NOTE:** `TItem` already derives from (and implements)`IComparable<T>`.

Comment: Do you always have to work with the original structure? You could always use a combination of IEnumerable.Sort and ToDictionary() to sort when needed given a certain field.

Comment: @Justin: Thanks.  Could you please post this as an answer?  Looks like it might be simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not going to be modifying the result of the sort, you could use a combination of IEnumerable.OrderBy and ToDictionary:

```
var sortedResult = sortedDictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.SortField)
                                   .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key,
                                                 kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Just keep in mind that this is really creating a new collection rather than sorting the original (which will be maintained in the SortedDictionary).

Answer (score 2):

The SortedDictionary class has a [Values property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zazzsd83.aspx) that "Gets a collection containing the values in the SortedDictionary". That collection is an IEnumerable and you can sort that collection of values.

Here is an example program in C# (I wrote it quickly as an example. It probably could be improved and/or changed based on your specific needs).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SortedDictionary<string, int> sd = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();

            sd.Add("a", 10);
            sd.Add("c", 4);
            sd.Add("b", 20);

            Console.WriteLine("___KEYS____");
            foreach (string key in sd.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(key);
            }

            foreach(int sortedVal in sd.Values.OrderBy(value => value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sortedVal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the items to a SortedList will only store references to the objects already in memory so it won't take up much more room.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to sort the dictionary's Values property, but if the list is large or the sorting function is expensive, this could be slower than you might wish - particularly if you're accessing it often.

Here's my quick and dirty implementation of a sorted dictionary.  It uses a Dictionary for direct access, but also keeps ListDictionary instances for sorted access of keys or values.

You can sort on any field or expression.  If your sort includes method calls, however, the functions should be deterministic (so that given a set of values, they are always sorted the same way).  Also note, the items are sorted upon insertion - if the objects are updated afterwards, sort order is not automatically updated.  If this is a possibility, you're better off using LINQ to sort upon demand.

```
public class ArbitrarySortedDictionary<TKEY, TSORT, TVALUE> : IDictionary<TKEY, TVALUE> 
    where TSORT : IComparable
    where TKEY : IComparable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Key class for use in keeping the _SortedKeys and _SortedValues in proper order.  Since the sorting 
    /// function could easily result in same values across instances, we'll use the key as secondary sort
    /// field - since it's unique, everything should always have a consistent, unambiguous sort order.
    /// </summary>
    class SortedDictionaryKey
    {
        public SortedDictionaryKey(TSORT sortVal, TKEY key)
        {
            SortVal = sortVal;
            Key = key;
        }

        public TSORT SortVal
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public TKEY Key
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }

    readonly Func<TVALUE, TSORT> _SortFunc;
    readonly Dictionary<TKEY, TVALUE> _InternalDict = new Dictionary<TKEY, TVALUE>();
    readonly SortedList<SortedDictionaryKey, TKEY> _SortedKeys;
    readonly SortedList<SortedDictionaryKey, TVALUE> _SortedValues;


    public ArbitrarySortedDictionary(Func<TVALUE, TSORT> sortFunc)
    {
        _SortFunc = sortFunc;

        Func<SortedDictionaryKey, SortedDictionaryKey, Int32> compFunc = (x, y) => {
            Int32 sortValComp = 0;

            if (x.SortVal != null)
                sortValComp = x.SortVal.CompareTo(y.SortVal);

            if (sortValComp != 0)
                return sortValComp;

            if (x.Key != null)
                return x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key);

            return y.Key == null ? 0 : -1;
        };

        var comparer = new LambdaComparer<SortedDictionaryKey>(compFunc);

        _SortedKeys = new SortedList<SortedDictionaryKey, TKEY>(comparer);
        _SortedValues = new SortedList<SortedDictionaryKey, TVALUE>(comparer);
    }

    public void Add(TKEY key, TVALUE value)
    {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Null key is not allowed.");

        var sortKey = new SortedDictionaryKey(_SortFunc(value), key);

        _InternalDict.Add(key, value);
        _SortedKeys.Add(sortKey, key);
        _SortedValues.Add(sortKey, value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKEY key)
    {
        return _InternalDict.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public ICollection<TKEY> Keys
    {
        get {
            return _SortedKeys.Values.ToList<TKEY>();
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(TKEY key)
    {
        return RemoveInternal(key, _InternalDict[key]);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKEY key, out TVALUE value)
    {
        return _InternalDict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICollection<TVALUE> Values
    {
        get {
            return _SortedValues.Values.ToList<TVALUE>();
        }
    }

    public TVALUE this[Int32 index]
    {
        get {
            return _InternalDict[_SortedKeys.Values[index]];
        }
        set {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Can't update ArbitrarySortedDictionary directly.");
        }
    }

    public TVALUE this[TKEY key]
    {
        get {
            return _InternalDict[key];
        }
        set {
            if (!ContainsKey(key)) {
                Add(key, value);
                return;
            }

            throw new NotImplementedException("To update items currently, remove and re-add.");
        }
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKEY, TVALUE> item)
    {
        var sortKey = new SortedDictionaryKey(_SortFunc(item.Value), item.Key);

        _InternalDict.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        _SortedKeys.Add(sortKey, item.Key);
        _SortedValues.Add(sortKey, item.Value);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _SortedKeys.Clear();
        _SortedValues.Clear();
        _InternalDict.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKEY, TVALUE> item)
    {
        var val = _InternalDict[item.Key];

        if (val == null)
            return item.Value == null;

        return val.Equals(item.Value);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKEY, TVALUE>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        Int32 curIndex = arrayIndex;

        foreach (var item in this)
            array[curIndex++] = item;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _InternalDict.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKEY, TVALUE> item)
    {
        return RemoveInternal(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKEY, TVALUE>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var res =
            from k in _SortedKeys
            join v in _SortedValues on k.Key equals v.Key
            orderby k.Key
            select new KeyValuePair<TKEY, TVALUE>(k.Value, v.Value);

        return res.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }


    private Boolean RemoveInternal(TKEY key, TVALUE val)
    {
        if (!_InternalDict.Remove(key))
            return false;

        var sortKey = new SortedDictionaryKey(_SortFunc(val), key);
        var retVal = _SortedKeys.Remove(sortKey);
        return retVal && _SortedValues.Remove(sortKey);
    }
}





/// <summary>
/// Utility class - an IComparer based upon a lambda expression.
/// </summary>
public class LambdaComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, int> _lambdaHash;
    private readonly Func<T, T, int> _lambdaComparer;

    public LambdaComparer(Func<T, T, int> lambdaComparer) :
        this(lambdaComparer, o => 0)
    {
    }

    public LambdaComparer(Func<T, T, int> lambdaComparer, Func<T, int> lambdaHash)
    {
        if (lambdaComparer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lambdaComparer");

        if (lambdaHash == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lambdaHash");

        _lambdaHash = lambdaHash;
        _lambdaComparer = lambdaComparer;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return _lambdaComparer(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _lambdaHash(obj);
    }
}
```